# Event listener only for a variable

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
var right = document.getElementsByClassName("dreapta")[0];

function scaleText(){
    right.style.backgroundColor = "#111";
    right.style.color = "white";
}
right.addEventListener('click', scaleText, false);
```

Can someone explain to me why the event is not working?

Comment: Put the `html` part too. The js part looks ok.

Comment: Provided that A) The element exists as of when you run that code, and B) You're using a modern browser in standards mode, not IE8 or IE9-11 in any of their broken "compatibility modes," [it **does** work](http://jsfiddle.net/orvdnnwx/). So presumably, the element *doesn't* exist as of when you're running that code. I'm sure this is a duplicate of a dozen questions, but I'm not finding any non-jQuery ones.

Comment: What doesn't work? Is there a JS error, do you believe the handler doesn't run, or does the style not update in the way you expect?

Comment: <div class="dreapta"></div> the div has a width of 33% and height auto;
I don't know why the handler doesn;t work. @joews

Comment: @Stefan: Again, it **does**. Post an [MCVE](/help/mcve) demonstrating exactly the code that isn't working, and we can tell you what's wrong, but it's going to be one of the items from my comment above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder i'm using Chrome
for example when i use onclick = scaleText; 
it is working but when i use the code i wrote in my example it doesn't,

Comment: @Stefan: Third time: The code you've shown **works** (follow [the link](http://jsfiddle.net/orvdnnwx/)!) given reasonable assumptions. So post what **doesn't** work so we can point out which reasonable assumption was mistaken.

Comment: The code i wrote is working on the jsfiddle  but i  don't know why is not working on mine .

Answer (score 0):

The problem was from my HTML,i had an audio tag which had to be removed.
Now is working :).Ty guys and sorry for bothering.

Comment: Since this answer is based on information not in the question, the best solution here is to delete the question. Glad you figured it out.